# ReSharper's Code Cleanup Tool Does Nothing after Being Run

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-8.0

I am in VS 2012.  I run the tool on a fairly large .sln.  It runs, but only opens up about 5 classes.  I've set the clean profile to do suff such as removing redundant "this" qualifiers, remove unused using statements, etc.

It only ran for about a minute.

**When it was done I noticed the following:**

- there were barely any files opened and even in those files the cleanup did nothing meaning I could still see those were not cleaned, I still see unused using statements, etc.

I am using R# **8.1.23.546**

Comment: If you run the silent cleanup (ctrl-alt-shift-f) on a single file, does it do what you expect?

Comment: yes it did, strange...let me look at this some more

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Solved it by first running the resharper preset "reformat code".
It's important to let the files reopen for undoing and answer popup questions for this with "yes".
After thats done you can run your own setup.